# What is the difference between asText() and toString() in JsonNode?

Tags: java, json, string

So I'm trying to validate some payload after POSTing.

The payload (JSON) looks like the follow:

```
{"value":"\"<html><body><a href='http://www.example.com'>Hi there!</a></body></html>\""}
```

Then I tried to convert the above to JsonNode and extract the "*value*"'s value. However, the two methods, `asText()` & `toString()`, return different string values.

How do these two methods work differently?

Given the String `"\"<html><body><a href='http://www.example.com'>Hi there!</a></body></html>\""`

**toString** returns `"<html><body><a href='http://www.example.com'>Hi there!</a></body></html>"`

**asText()** returns `<html><body><a href='http://www.example.com'>Hi there!</a></body></html>`

Comment: The first is serialized as JSON, the second is not.

Comment: @shmosel, okay, that made sense. But what is the result of asText() method serialized as?

Comment: It's not serialized. It's just a string value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[`asText ()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText())**

It is an abstract method from [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText()), which is overriden in  [`TextNode`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.java). And, as per its implementation,  it supposed to return the value without any manipulation.

```
@Override
public String asText() {
    return _value;
}
```

**[`toString ()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)**

It is overridden from [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). So, it is ***textual representation of an object***. So, `toString` actually returns you the complete textual form on your given object. And, per its implementation in `TextNode`. It appends quoting (at the beginning and end) to your value.

```
/**
 * Different from other values, Strings need quoting
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    int len = _value.length();
    len = len + 2 + (len >> 4);
    return new StringBuilder(len)
            // 09-Dec-2017, tatu: Use apostrophes on purpose to prevent use as JSON producer:
            .append('\'')
            .append(_value)
            .append('\'')
            .toString();
}
```

And, you can also see the same difference when you print them.

Comment: I think this makes sense. So when the payload is serialized as JSON, the actual value becomes the html string, and asText() returns as it is, and toString() will add quotation marks around the html string. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @JackZhang Yes and this is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I will add is that if the string is very long, for me, only using `.toString()` worked as the other two (`.asText()` and `.textValue()`) would return empty string and null respectively.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR:

- Only the master branch has the behaviour of the accepted answer; versions before that, like Jackson 2.9, `toString()` does more than just "adding quotations around the string".
- If you want to check the text representation of some JsonNode which contains an key-value pair(an JSON object), you have to use `toString()`; `asText()` will get you `""`, because it is not a `ValueNode`. And, in this process, Unicode (`\uxxxx`) will be translated to actual characters.

In detail:

I tested with the lib I have and then I found I cannot agree with the accepted answer. Mine is 2.9.

In my case `toString()` does more than just add quotations. It will also perserve the escaping characters in the string content, at least from version 2.0 to 2.9.

Check the source [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.0/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.java)(mind the version in URL. You can choose the version in the page, till 2.10)

2.0:

```
/**
 * Different from other values, Strings need quoting
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    int len = _value.length();
    len = len + 2 + (len >> 4);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    appendQuoted(sb, _value);
    return sb.toString();
}

protected static void appendQuoted(StringBuilder sb, String content)
{
    sb.append('"');
    CharTypes.appendQuoted(sb, content);
    sb.append('"');
}
```

`fasterxml.jackson.core.io.CharTypes.appendQuoted()` will perserve some escape characters. Check its source at [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/CharTypes.java).(Note the code is from 2.0 branch, not master)

```
public static void appendQuoted(StringBuilder sb, String content)
{
    final int[] escCodes = sOutputEscapes128;
    int escLen = escCodes.length;
    for (int i = 0, len = content.length(); i < len; ++i) {
        char c = content.charAt(i);
        if (c >= escLen || escCodes[c] == 0) {
            sb.append(c);
            continue;
        }
        sb.append('\\');
        int escCode = escCodes[c];
        if (escCode < 0) { // generic quoting (hex value)
            // We know that it has to fit in just 2 hex chars
            sb.append('u');
            sb.append('0');
            sb.append('0');
            int value = -(escCode + 1);
            sb.append(HEX_CHARS[value >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEX_CHARS[value & 0xF]);
        } else { // "named", i.e. prepend with slash
            sb.append((char) escCode);
        }
    }
}
```

But, now the `master` branch seems to simplify this behaviour to "only adding quotations", just as the accepted answer said. This can be seen in [this page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/93e18887907bd84bc7cbbddeadb656811477796f). Actually, this commit has the title of

> Remove dependency to CharTypes.appendQuoted(); change quotes of `JsonNode.toString()` to single quotes to try to prevent use for JSON generation

But again, I am using 2.9 and `CharTypes.appendQuoted()` is still used. So, normally, if you are not using the master branch, `toString()` will perserve the escaping characters.

Example:

```
JsonNode node = new TextNode("{\"en_us\":\"54\",\"es_es\":\"54\"}");
node.asText();  // -> {"en_us":"54","es_es":"54"}, no quotations, no escaping
node.toString(); // -> "{\"en_us\":\"54\",\"es_es\":\"54\"}", add quotations, perserves escaping.
```

So, mind with versions of lib is not always the "master"!

---

As for `toString()` of a `JsonNode` with object, check this:(Jackson data-bind 2.9)

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) node).put("es_es", "Categor\u00eda ra\u00edz/CATEGORY_OMS_DATA/");

    System.out.println((node.toString())); // {"es_es":"Categoría raíz/CATEGORY_OMS_DATA/"}, note: not quotations around!! not like TextNode!
    System.out.println(node.asText()); // empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between asText() and toString()

public abstract String **asText()**

Method that will return a valid String representation of the container value, if the node is a value node (method isValueNode() returns true), otherwise empty String.

```
public String readNameNode()
        {
            JsonNode nameNode=rootNode.path("name");
            String name=nameNode.asText();
            logger.info("\n----------------------------\nEmployee Name: "+name+"\n");
            return name;
        }
```

public abstract String **toString()**

Note: marked as abstract to ensure all implementation classes define it properly.

Overrides:
toString in class

```
public String readNameNode()
        {
            JsonNode nameNode=rootNode.path("name");
            String name=nameNode.toString();
            logger.info("\n----------------------------\nEmployee Name: "+name+"\n");
            return name;
        }
```

Hope so you understood the exact difference between asText method and toString method